# WPF Data Templates and Buttons

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2012

I have the following DataTemplate (note: there is a TextBlock and Button)

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ctlDefs:myButton}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelText}" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>

        <Button Content="{Binding LabelText}" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
            Width="{Binding ButtonWidth}" 
            Height="35"
            Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" 
            Visibility="Visible"                    
            />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

My screen is dynamically adding controls of myButton to an Items Control

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CommandButtons, Mode=OneWay}"
               FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
               DockPanel.Dock="Right"
              >
```

The first time I render the view,  the Textblock shows up for each button, but the Button itself does not.  If I hide the view and then show it again, the button will appear sometimes (if the CommandButtons list does not change, if it changes, it never shows).

After rendering the view, I looked in the Output window and no binding errors.

What am I missing.

Comment: Does this also happen if you don't bind the Width of Button? Does ButtonWidth implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes.  If I remove the ButtonWidth, it functions the same way. From what I can tell from using a WPF inspector, the button looks like it is there (space reserved for it), and all the properties match from the first to second load when it does show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've knocked up a quick application to work with your sample code and didn't seem to have any issues with the view. Below is what it looks like when run.

[image: Looks like this]

I've included my code below in case it helps. **Note: I didn't add a real ICommand object for brevity and I accidentally named the MyButton class with capital M instead of small m like your example**

ViewModelBase.cs

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.CommandButtons = new ObservableCollection<MyButton>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MyButton> CommandButtons { get; private set; }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var mainvm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        var window = new MainWindow
        {
            DataContext = mainvm
        };
        window.Show();

        mainvm.CommandButtons.Add(new MyButton { ButtonWidth = 50, LabelText = "Button 1" });
        mainvm.CommandButtons.Add(new MyButton { ButtonWidth = 50, LabelText = "Button 2" });
        mainvm.CommandButtons.Add(new MyButton { ButtonWidth = 50, LabelText = "Button 3" });
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ctlDefs="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ctlDefs:MyButton}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelText}" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>

            <Button Content="{Binding LabelText}" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
                    Width="{Binding ButtonWidth}" 
                    Height="35"
                    Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" 
                    Visibility="Visible"                    
        />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CommandButtons, Mode=OneWay}"
           FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
           DockPanel.Dock="Right"
          />
</Grid>
```

MyButton.cs

```
public class MyButton : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _labelText;

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return this._labelText; }
        set { this._labelText = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("LabelText"); }
    }

    private double _buttonWidth;

    public double ButtonWidth
    {
        get { return _buttonWidth; }
        set { _buttonWidth = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("ButtonWidth"); }
    }

    private ICommand _buttonCommand;

    public ICommand ButtonCommand
    {
        get { return _buttonCommand; }
        set { _buttonCommand = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("ButtonCommand"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have your code working on my machine, there was a couple differences ObservableCollection vs List on the CommandButtons);  ICommand vs DelegateCommand.

I made these changes and mine is still not working.  I am thinking there is something else going on.

thanks for your help in verifying that this approach works. I will try to simplify my larger project and see where I get.

I accepted this as the answer, because it is how it "Should" work.

Comment: Can't click the Up arrow because my rep is not high enough  :-(

Comment: Finally narrowed it down.  In my style file, there was this entry

`<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource NuclearButtonFocusVisual}" /><Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}" />
        <!--<Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonTemplate}" />-->
    </Style>`

the commented out line was the issue, but not sure why

Comment: Glad you worked it out! You need to check the definition of ButtonTemplate and see if you have included all the PART defintions that you need. Also delegate command is correct to use, I normally hook this up in my constructor. this.Command = new DelegateCommand(o  => this.MyMethod();